# Spring does not inject SessionFactory when calling CustomValidator second Time

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am developing a application using spring and hibernate. i have created a custom validator for for checking duplicate value in the database for that i need to inject hibernate SessionFactory in the CustomValidator. it works fine for on a single field but when i apply it on two or more field i get a NullPointerException it seems like spring does not inject the SessionFactory while calling validator second time.

here is code of entity class

```
  public class CenterRegistration implements Serializable {
@Column(unique=true)
@UniqueKey(message="Email Id already exist please choose another Email Id ", table =   "CenterRegistration", column = "email")
private String email;

@UniqueKey(message="UserName already exist please choose another username", table = "CenterRegistration", column = "userName")
@Column(unique = true)
private String userName;
```

And here is code of customvalidator implementing class

```
  public class UserNameConstraintValidator implements
    ConstraintValidator<UniqueKey, String> {

@Inject
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    System.out.println("in is valid value=" + value + " " + sessionFactory);
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        return true;
    }
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

it works fine when i apply this validator on a single field on my entity but when applying on second spring injects null into the sessionfactory.

```
if (sessionFactory == null) {
        return true;
    }
```

i have used these just to avoid NullPointerException.

Comment: try using "@Autowired" instate of "@Inject" as both work same

Comment: I had a bug once when 2 validators were active in my app at the same time. Spring was validating the forms with it's own validator and hibernate also validated beans again before persisting them using another validator. I haven't noticed it until I needed to inject something into my custom validation validator - injecting didn't work in hibernate's built in validator. Probably isn't issue here but worth checking.

Comment: yeah you are right Kresimir Nesek validation is performed 2 times once by spring and then by hibernate before persisting. but even also when validation is performed by hibernate SessionFactory does not get injected. i noticed it by printing the sessionFactory on console.